# Error reading settings.xml: Expected root element 'settings' but found 'servers' (position: START_TAG seen <servers>

Tags: maven

I downloaded an existing Maven project into eclipse.

When I ran `mvn install` using the `pom.xml` file it failed showing the following error:

```
 mvn install
 Error reading settings.xml: Expected root element 'settings' but found 'servers' 
 (position: START_TAG seen  <servers>... @1:10)
 Line:   1
 Column: 10
```

I am using Maven 2.2.1 . and got settings.xml file under the M2 Home

Comment: Without a copy of your settings file we must assume it is invalid. You're mostly likely missing the root XML tag "settings".

Answer (score 7):

I got this error in [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij) (so the warning is not IDE specific) having imported a project using the POM at `spring-data-neo4j-examples/cineasts/pom.xml` on [github](/questions/tagged/github)

My `settings.xml` file contained the following

```
  <server>
        <id>LocalTomcat</id>
        <username>tomcat</username>
        <password>tomcat</password>
  </server>
```

Looking at http://maven.apache.org/settings.html I found the following settings template which contains the appropriate namespaces.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

I dropped in the original `<server>` settings into the  element.

The warning no longer occurred upon running `mvn compile`